# How to prove the set $A = \left\{ \frac 1{2^n} \mid n \in \mathbb N\right\}$ is an infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have started to learn in university, and the way they teach us is very simpled... not the way they tought as geometry. The question is simple, but I want an concrete simple mathematic proof(verbal would be enough) something that would help me grasp the concept:

I have this set $$A = \left\{ \frac 1{2^n} \mid  n \in \mathbb N\right\}$$ and I need to prove it to be infinite.

I know that $\mathbb N$, the set of natural numbers, is an infinite set, but they don't want me to rely on that, since the second part of the question is to prove their correlation.

So the question is, how do I prove that a set is infinite using simple concepts of sets?

Comment: How is that a group?  How are the natural numbers a group?

Comment: I am new to math so I may be saying wrong things, ℕ is group of all Natural numbers {1,2,3,4...}

Comment: When you use the word "group" do you mean to say "set"?  Because A is a set, not a group.

Comment: That's not a group.  Your set $A$ is obviously in bijection with $\mathbb N$, so the fact that it is infinite is trivial.  Not sure what you are asking otherwise.

Comment: At least in Hebrew, in a non-mathematical context, it's common to translate the word for "set" (קבוצה) as "group". So when facing English terms for the first time, many people make this mistake. I guess the issue here is similar.

Comment: I changed that, thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to work around the fact you've been given the set of elements which is infinite. Almost any proof you can come up with kind of uses that. However, how about a proof by contradiction. Suppose $A$ were finite of order $x$. Then you can write down an element of $A$ which generates a finite subgroup of order more than $x$, a clear contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by "of order   x"? I mean I don't know what order means in the concept of sets

Comment: for finite sets, order is the number of elements

Comment: @Vasya: I have *never* heard this term being used that way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: in Russian, "order" is often used as synonym to "cardinality" :)

Comment: It's common parlance in group theory -- "Let $G$ be a group of order 16..."

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Assume $A$ is finite. Certainly $1/2 \in A$. Then $A$ has a minimal element, say $a$. Then, $a^2 \in A$. Since $a$ is minimal, $a \le 1/2$.

Find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Note $\mathbf N$ is *not* a group (natural numbers have no additive inverse).
Your  group $A$ is in bijection with $\mathbf N$, by the map $n\longmapsto\frac1{2^n}$.

Indeed this map is injective, because if $n\ne n'$, say $n<n'$, then $$\frac1{2^{n'}}=\frac1{2^n}\cdot\frac1{2^{\mkern1mu\smash[b]{\underbrace{n'-n}_{>0}}}}<\frac1{2^n}.$$

Also it is surjective by the very definition of $A$. Hence $A$ is infinite (countable, may we add).

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I meant set, the diffrence from hebrew to english got me a mistake.

Comment: Is it a group? What's the inverse of $\frac12$ in this group?

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I everywhere thought of exponents as being  in $\mathbf Z$.